# twisted python daemonization and port bindings

Tags: python, twisted, daemon, twistd

I am using the following script from the Twisted tutorial (with slight modification):

```
from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, defer
from twisted.protocols import basic
from twisted.web import client

class FingerProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):

    def lineReceived(self, user):
        d = self.factory.getUser(user)

        def onError(err):
            return "Internal server error"
        d.addErrback(onError)

        def writeResponse(message):
            self.transport.write(message + "\r\n")
            self.transport.loseConnection()
        d.addCallback(writeResponse)

class FingerFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):
    protocol = FingerProtocol

    def __init__(self, prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix

    def getUser(self, user):
        return client.getPage(self.prefix + user)

application = service.Application('finger', uid=1, gid=1)
factory = FingerFactory(prefix="http://livejournal.com/~")
internet.TCPServer(7979, factory).setServiceParent(
    service.IServiceCollection(application))
```

which I save as `finger_daemon.tac` and run with

```
twistd -y finger_daemon.tac \ 
    -l /home/me/twisted/finger.log \
    --pidfile=/home/me/twisted/finger.pid
```

but of course it won't bind to 79, since it's a privileged port. I tried also running with sudo, no difference there.

I then tried changing the `TCPServer` port to 7979 and then connecting to the daemon once running with

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 7979
```

and I get `Connection Refused` error. What's going on here specifically? How is daemonizing supposed to work in Twisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run this code, I see the following log message:

```
2013-10-02 23:50:34-0700 [-] failed to set uid/gid 1/1 (are you root?) -- exiting.
```

and then `twistd` exits.  So you'd need to do `sudo twistd` and then that adds a whole bunch of python path management problems...

Why are you setting the `uid` and `gid` arguments?  You're trying to run it as the `daemon` user?  You don't need to do that in order to daemonize.  Just removing the `uid=1, gid=1` arguments to `Application` makes it work for me.

Comment: also importantly - how did you see the error? twistd runs silently for me

Comment: I work on Twisted, so a direct link to the tutorial that mentions this example would be useful :-).

Comment: I saw the error by running `twistd -n -y finger_daemon.tac`.  With your invocation, you should have seen the same error though, just in `/home/me/twisted/finger.log`.  (Although startup errors are not always reported correctly; it would be interesting to know whether you saw that or not!)

Comment: Here's one example of the uid/gid = 1 indictions: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tutorial/style.html